# Why can't I see the color of an object with from shader nodes?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I'm new Blender user weehooo!
my machine details:
[image: screenshot of device properties]
I'm using the last version of Blender 3.0.0

I started my first project following this YouTube tutorial: [Flag animation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xSGM-hMQrY) and when I got into the adding shading color to the flag by using material properties without using the nodes on the shading editor nodes all work well:

[image: Screenshot showing color]

and when I tap the use nodes and then change the color in the Diffuse node there (marks in pic) I can't actually change the color.

[image: screen shot of problem]

Any ideas why? thanks for being there for newbies like me :) great day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Viewport Display modes]

Blender has four *Viewport Display* modes for the 3D Viewport.  The first two of these do not show the colors that you place in a shader.  The second two, the pair that I have labeled "Render" and "Preview" do.

If you want to see the colors from your shader, I recommend using Preview mode for now.  The four modes are found in the 3D Viewport *Top Bar*.  They are on the far right, and if you have a small display, they may be off screen.  In that case, you have to use the mouse to drag the top bar to the left to show them.

Click on the the image to change the mode.

Comment: hey Marty thanks for quick answer! that's was it. there is a way to mark question as solved?

Comment: When you clicked the checkmark you marked the question as solved.  The Stackexchange word is "accepted", but it serves the same purpose.  I hope you don't mind that I edited your question.  Stackexchange likes question titles to be useful for searching by other people with similar questions